# A way of disposing scripts files previously loaded with $.getScript()

Tags: jquery, getscript

Sorry about my English. I'm developing a chess interactive site. There is a lesson menu, when the user selects the lesson, it's loaded using `$.getScript()`. Lesson file only has a variable `lesson` that contains a "big" json object. When user selects another lesson, file is loaded and the new `lesson` var overrides the previous one.

Ok, that works great. But, should I dispose the previous loaded file/s, and if I should, how I do that? What if the user navigates fifty lessons, will it slow down the process?

I took a look in firebug when the file is loaded and the `<head>`, where supposedly `$.getScript()` put the file, and it makes a 'yellow flash', but nothing visible is added.

I would want to know your thoughts about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you'd 'dispose' the file, or delete the script tag or whatever, your script already has been exeuted, and therefore, your variables exist.

The only way would be to set to `null` your json objects when you select another lesson.

For example, if you have the following json in the `lesson1.js` file:

```
var lesson1data = { 
  ...Big json comes here...
};
```

In your main page/script you should have:

```
function selectLesson(lessonNumber){
   lesson1data = null; //This 'cleans' the loaded data
   lesson2data = null; //This 'cleans' the loaded data
   ...
   $.getScript(...); //Load json data for selected lesson
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: The json object var in "memory" is not a problem, because it's allways overrided by the new one.

Comment: Ahh, You didn't say the var name is the same. If so, you don't have to do anything, there will be only 1 at a time

Comment: Yes, all files contains only: `var lesson = { ... };`. I did a quick test loading some tens of lessons and browser memory usage doesn't seem to change.

Comment: So you don't have to worry. Even if script tags weren't deleted, they wouldn'be a considerable overhead. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getScript` doesn't actually load the file (i.e. appending it to the head as a script tag) but downloads the script .js file and runs it immediately. Of course, you could include some kind of terminating function in your script that wipes itself out when you are done using it.

Comment: Like my other comment, the object var/s "in memory" are not a problem, because it's only one and allways overrided by the new lesson. But I don't know if the whole files are stored somewhere, in the page or in the browser memory.